# Aligning mat-spinner in bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

I have a mat-spinner in a bootstrap row. I want to right align the mat-spinner in the row:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="spinner-wrapper">
      <mat-spinner [diameter]="30" value="indeterminate">
      </mat-spinner>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried following things individually on the spinner-wrapper class, but did not work:

`margin: 0 auto;`

`text-align: right;`

`float: right;`

None of these worked.

How can I right-align the mat-spinner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this css properties to each element:

```
.spinner-wrapper{
   text-align:right;
}

mat-spinner{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Hope it help.